# Isn't Groth-Sahai proof system applicable beyond Bilinear groups?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Classical paper by Groth-Sahai on NIZK proof system is titled as "*Efficient Non-interactive Proof Systems for Bilinear Groups*". To my understanding, only (Pairing Product Equation) PPE are defined over groups which induces Bilinear map. But, what about (Multi-Scalar Multiplication Equation) MSME/ (Quadratic Equation) QE? Aren't those applicable to generic groups, too? In that sense, isn't the tile of the paper a misnomer?

Specifically, I am talking about the equations below:

[image]

Comment: What is PPE? $\:$ What are MSME and QE? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky Demer I have edited original post to fill up information gaps. Please have a second look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are applicable to groups other than elliptic curves with bilinear pairing, if that's what you mean with "groups which induces Bilinear map". Consider for example the group $\mathbb{Z}_q$. They DO have a bilinear operation, namely $f: \mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q \to \mathbb{Z}_q$ s.t. $f(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old thread. A group is defined by the underlying set and the operation on the set. As you say, $\mathbb{Z}_q$, are you talking about $\mathbb{Z}_q^+$ or $\mathbb{Z}_q^{\ast}$ or both? I can see bilinearity to hold on $\mathbb{Z}_n^+$ but not on $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\ast}$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ being modulo group of integers. The operations I was referring to is addition modulo $n$ and multiplication modulo $n$ respectively.

Comment: The operation here is a plus, else it would be not a group, because $0\in \mathbb{Z}_q$ is not invertible with the operation $*$.